# Using "DELETE" sentence in "BEFORE INSERT" trigger: met ERROR - Can't Update table ... used by statement which invoked stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, mysql-8.0

### problem descriptions

I know that sentences in a trigger should never invoke the trigger itself, but i think i didn't while error still occurred in this case (i'll write below). So I'm really puzzled and could anyone help to correct me.

I'm using MySQL 8.0

### what i encountered

Here is my tables in the database:

| CodeName | Password | Permission | Class | Region | Race | Avatar | Mail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 456 | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| Amiya | amiya | 1 | Caster | Rim Billiton | Cautus | NULL | NULL |
| Doctor | bbtdel | 1 | NULL | Unknown | Unknown | NULL | NULL |
| hhh | 1234 | 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| P.R.T.S | prts | 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| qwert | dsfrg | 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| test | test | 2 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I tried to create a trigger that will be invoked before `insert`ing a record. if the new record's `CodeName` matches anyone that has already existed in the table, then i will delete  the matched old one before this `insert`

Here's how i create my trigger:

```sql
create trigger trig_when_insert
before insert on user_account
for each row
begin
    call del_by_codename(NEW.CodeName);
end
```

`del_by_codename()` was a store procedure that i created for practice (in fact this trigger is created for practice as well and it seems stupid).

Here's how i create the procedure:

```sql
create procedure del_by_codename(in tar_codename char(30))
begin
    delete from user_account
    where CodeName = tar_codename;
end
```

after the trigger was build, any `insert` operation to this table will arouse the error:

> ERROR 1442 (HY000): Can't update table 'user_account' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Is 'delete' part of the 'insert'? Really puzzled

Comment: True and there is no way round it..Consider putting delete and insert in a transaction and/or INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY

Comment: "Is 'delete' part of the 'insert'?" - No, `DELETE` is part of 'update' in "Can't update table". That means you can not do **any** changes to that table in your trigger, which includes  `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE`. For a solution - see the comment above.